# Separate bank account for second app?

Tags: app-store-connect

I am developing an iOS application for a business associate of mine. Is it possible to associate a second bank account for the revenues of that application? Or do all funds generated from a single Apple ID flow into a single bank account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't associate a bank account with an app.

You could have different bank accounts for every single contract you sign with apple:

- iOS Paid Applications
- iAd App Network